# How can I write a dynamically updated panel app / indicator?

Tags: python, panel, programming, c++, mate

I am trying to write some panel apps for ubuntu Mate. 
I know C/C++, and SDL reasonably well. 
I have seen the Mate-University panel apps github page, but i cannot get it to work properly / Im having a though time with it.

I am just wondering, if there is some easy avenue to write panel apps? I am not talking about using the custom application launcher, I would like to add new functionality, to the panel, but Im not sure how to.  A tutorial, or description about writing panel apps could be really helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since what seems to be the occasion to ask this question already [has an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/752675/72216), I am answering this question as an extended explanation on how it was done (in `python`)

#### Basic *static* indicator

Since Ubuntu Mate, from 15,10, supports indicators, there is not much difference between writing an indicator and a panel app for Mate. Therefore, [this link](http://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html) is a good starting point for a basic indicator in `python`, using the `AppIndicator3` API. The link is a nice start, but does not provide any information on how to show text on the indicator, let alone how to *update* the text (or icon). Nevertheless, with a few additions, this leads to a basic "frame" of an indicator as below. It will show an icon, a text label and a menu:

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'test123'
        iconpath = "/opt/abouttime/icon/indicator_icon.png"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())
        self.indicator.set_label("1 Monkey", self.app)

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        # menu item 1
        item_1 = Gtk.MenuItem('Menu item')
        # item_about.connect('activate', self.about)
        menu.append(item_1)
        # separator
        menu_sep = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        menu.append(menu_sep)
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)

        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

In the line `AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER`, the category is defined, as explaned in [this (partially outdated) link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators). Setting the right category is important, a.o. to put the indicator in an appropriate position in the panel.

#### The main challenge; how to update the indicator text and/or icon

The real challenge is not how to write a basic indicator, but how to periodically *update* the text and/or icon of your indicator, since you want to have it show the (textual) time. To make the indicator work properly, we cannot simply use `threading` to start a second process to periodically update the interface. Well, actually we can, but on a longer run, it will lead to conflicts, as I found out.

Here is where `GObject` comes in, to, as it is put [in this (also outdated) link](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=edit&file=faq20.006.htp):

*call `gobject.threads_init()` at applicaiton initialization. Then you launch your threads normally, but make sure the threads never do any GUI tasks directly. Instead, you use `gobject.idle_add` to schedule GUI task to executed in the main thread*

When we replace `gobject.threads_init()`  by `GObject.threads_init()` and `gobject.idle_add` by `GObject.idle_add()`, we pretty much have the updated version of how to run threads in a `Gtk` application. A simplified example, showing an increasing number of Monkeys:

[image]

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GObject
import time
from threading import Thread

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'test123'
        iconpath = "/opt/abouttime/icon/indicator_icon.png"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())
        self.indicator.set_label("1 Monkey", self.app)
        # the thread:
        self.update = Thread(target=self.show_seconds)
        # daemonize the thread to make the indicator stopable
        self.update.setDaemon(True)
        self.update.start()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        # menu item 1
        item_1 = Gtk.MenuItem('Menu item')
        # item_about.connect('activate', self.about)
        menu.append(item_1)
        # separator
        menu_sep = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        menu.append(menu_sep)
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)

        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def show_seconds(self):
        t = 2
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            mention = str(t)+" Monkeys"
            # apply the interface update using  GObject.idle_add()
            GObject.idle_add(
                self.indicator.set_label,
                mention, self.app,
                priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                )
            t += 1

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
# this is where we call GObject.threads_init()
GObject.threads_init()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

---

That's the principle. In the actual indicator in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/752675/72216), both the loop time and the indicator text were determined by a secondary module, imported in the script, but the main idea is the same.