# How do I get the current power consumption in the status bar? (Developing a status icon)

Tags: statusbar

I wanted to ask how can I develop a simple script/app and put it in the status bar near the time (top right). Let's say I have a laptop and the script gets the battery current usage in watts every 10 seconds so it is shown in the status bar. Am using ubuntu 16 with unity

Comment: Hi Кристиян Кацаров, If you can give me the command to get the power consumption that works on your system, I can give you the answer. An edited version of this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/756519/72216 If you provide the information, I'll add an explanation.

Comment: Huh? you're kidding right? Instead of delivering relevant information I asked for, you hurry into accepting an answer that - with all respect - definitely will not give you the key to do what you asked for.

Comment: I chose it because I needed directions and not a ready written code. But thank you for your help too

Comment: *Directions* as in "try something with python". Ok, forget it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu provides a [set of libraries and examples for using them](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators) to for a migration of simple menus and a consistent interface.

The examples in the document linked above includes version is the following languages:

- C
- PYGI
- PYGTK
- C#
- Vala
- Haskell

**A python` example from the page is:**

```phthon
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2009-2012 Canonical Ltd.
#
# Authors: Neil Jagdish Patel <neil.patel@canonical.com>
#          Jono Bacon <jono@ubuntu.com>
#          David Planella <david.planella@ubuntu.com>
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it 
# under the terms of either or both of the following licenses:
#
# 1) the GNU Lesser General Public License version 3, as published by the 
# Free Software Foundation; and/or
# 2) the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1, as published by 
# the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but 
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranties of 
# MERCHANTABILITY, SATISFACTORY QUALITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR 
# PURPOSE.  See the applicable version of the GNU Lesser General Public 
# License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of both the GNU Lesser General Public 
# License version 3 and version 2.1 along with this program.  If not, see 
# <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
#

from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator


def menuitem_response(w, buf):
  print buf

if __name__ == "__main__":
  ind = appindicator.Indicator.new (
                        "example-simple-client",
                        "indicator-messages",
                        appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
  ind.set_status (appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
  ind.set_attention_icon ("indicator-messages-new")

  # create a menu
  menu = Gtk.Menu()

  # create some 
  for i in range(3):
    buf = "Test-undermenu - %d" % i

    menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem(buf)

    menu.append(menu_items)

    # this is where you would connect your menu item up with a function:

    # menu_items.connect("activate", menuitem_response, buf)

    # show the items
    menu_items.show()

  ind.set_menu(menu)

  Gtk.main()
```

You could use a program from the list as a wrapper for your script so that clicking on the item will call your script.

---

**Making Icon and text dynamic**

(Taken from: [How can I write a dynamically updated panel app / indicator?](http://pifuge.com/ubuntu/fE1O-how-can-i-write-a-dynamically-updated-panel-app-indicator?noredirect=1))

This example suggests using `GObject`.  Call `gobject.threads_init()`an application initialization.  Then launch your threads normally, but make sure the threads never do any GUI task directly.  Instead, you use `gobject.idle_add` to schedule GUI task directly.
(The above is an exact quote from the link included in case the link stops working.)

```phthon
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GObject
import time
from threading import Thread

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'test123'
        iconpath = "/opt/abouttime/icon/indicator_icon.png"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())
        self.indicator.set_label("1 Monkey", self.app)
        # the thread:
        self.update = Thread(target=self.show_seconds)
        # daemonize the thread to make the indicator stopable
        self.update.setDaemon(True)
        self.update.start()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        # menu item 1
        item_1 = Gtk.MenuItem('Menu item')
        # item_about.connect('activate', self.about)
        menu.append(item_1)
        # separator
        menu_sep = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        menu.append(menu_sep)
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)

        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def show_seconds(self):
        t = 2
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            mention = str(t)+" Monkeys"
            # apply the interface update using  GObject.idle_add()
            GObject.idle_add(
                self.indicator.set_label,
                mention, self.app,
                priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                )
            t += 1

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
# this is where we call GObject.threads_init()
GObject.threads_init()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: This is totally missing essential information on how to dynamically update the indicator. At best a comment.

Comment: @user72216 Thanks.  I thought the example might have been a little clearer to the user who had already programmed his script application.  I'll add an example of how it can be done to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of counting monkeys :-), I modified the second script from **L. D. James**'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/820858/566421) to **show the current power consumption of my laptop in watts**.

[image]

The script works with **Ubuntu 16.04** and probably the only system specific thing is the file where the value of the current power consumption is stored. In my case I found it by the help of `tlp`:

```bsh
$ sudo tlp stat | grep -P '\[m(W|A)\]'    # Output on Lenovo ThinkPad X230 Tablet
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =  11246 [mW]

$ sudo tlp stat | grep -P '\[m(W|A)\]'    # Output on Dell Vostro 3350 Laptop
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =  6700 [mA]
```

**Note** some devices provide the current power consumption in watts, but some devices provide the current values of the voltage and the current (amps) - and **the script covers these cases**.

Further I created the [GitHub Project PowerNow](https://github.com/pa4080/powerNow) and added additional options: to execute `htop`, `powertop` or `tlp stat` within a `gnome-terminal`.

[image]

Installation of the Python script `powerNow` and optionally Startup Applications (and ~/Desktop) `.desktop` files:

- Copy the script to `/usr/local/bin` to make it accessible as shell command system wide:

  ```bsh
  sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pa4080/powerNow/master/powerNow.py -O /usr/local/bin/powerNow
  sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/powerNow
  ```
- Copy the script to `~/bin` to make it accessible only for the current user:

  ```bsh
  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pa4080/powerNow/master/powerNow.py -O $HOME/bin/powerNow
  chmod +x $HOME/bin/powerNow
  ```
- Copy the desktop file to `~/Desktop` (the script is required):

  ```bsh
  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pa4080/powerNow/master/powerNow.desktop -O $HOME/Desktop/powerNow.desktop
  chmod +x $HOME/Desktop/powerNow.desktop
  ```
- Copy the desktop file to `~/.config/autostart` (the script is required):

  ```bsh
  wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pa4080/powerNow/master/powerNow.desktop -O $HOME/.config/autostart/powerNow.desktop
  chmod +x $HOME/.config/autostart/powerNow.desktop
  ```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Your version only supports only laptops with one battery. My Thinkpad has got two batteries, so I extended your code a bit to display both consumption of both batteries.