# Is there a way to display an icon only while my script is running?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gui

I'm very, very new to scripting. Here is the simple script (which works) that I've written, which displays an image when 5 minutes have passed:

```
sleep 300 && firefox file:///home/tasks/fiveminutes.jpg
```

Here's my question: sometimes I can't remember if I've started the timer. Is there a way to add a text or icon indication (ideally on the taskbar, but anywhere would be great) that appears for 5 minutes (from the moment I start the timer to the moment I end it)?

Thanks so much for any suggestions.

Comment: Bash is not the greatest way to handle desktop functions. You could look at zenity or yad, but they don't work that great with a sleep function.  If you would consider using Python, then that would be a very simple script that could use a GTK/wx system tray icon.

Comment: For a more complex bash solution with zenity, you can have a look at this code : https://github.com/john-davies/shellpomo/blob/master/shellpomo

Comment: Hi Dorian  - Thanks so much for your suggestions. I'd be happy to use Python, can you point me towards a how-to for the GTK/wx system tray icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can display a pop-up notification when the process starts. Just change your script to

```
notify-send "Your image will arrive" "after 5 minutes" && sleep 300 && firefox file:///home/tasks/fiveminutes.jpg
```

You can set the duration of the notification bubble with the `-t` parameter (and time in milliseconds) with the `notify-send` command, for example to set the duration for 5 minutes use

```
notify-send -t 300000 "heading" "text"
```

**but** this parameter may be ignored completely depending on your desktop environment (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110969/notify-send-ignores-timeout)).

Comment: Hi Pomsky, thanks for your suggestion. What I'm looking for is something that remains on the screen for the entire 5 minutes.

Comment: @Sage. There's a way to set the timeout for the notification bubble (see edit to the answer), but unfortunately it may not work in certain desktop environments.

Comment: Hi Pomsky - the notify-send -t solution works like a dream. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

Here is Python launcher, based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/820858/566421) and an additional research in Internet, that works nice in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import gi
import os
import subprocess
import sys
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GObject
import time
from threading import Thread

# Execute the script
script = os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:])
script_name = script.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'Script indicator'
        iconpath = "/usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_bfb.png"

        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())
        self.indicator.set_label("Script Indicator", self.app)
        # the thread:
        self.update = Thread(target=self.show_seconds)
        # daemonize the thread to make the indicator stopable
        self.update.setDaemon(True)
        self.update.start()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        # menu item 1
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)

        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def show_seconds(self):
        global script_name
        t = 0
        process = subprocess.call(['pgrep', script_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        while (process == 0):
            t += 1
            GObject.idle_add(
                self.indicator.set_label,
                script_name + ' ' + str(t) + 's', self.app,
                priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                )
            time.sleep(1)
            process = subprocess.call(['pgrep', script_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        subprocess.call(['notify-send', script_name + ' ended in ' + str(t) + 's'])
        time.sleep(10)
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def stop(self, source):
        global script_name
        subprocess.call(['pkill', script_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
# this is where we call GObject.threads_init()
GObject.threads_init()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

- If you see any way to improve the script, please, do not hesitate to edit the answer. I haven't much experience with Python.

---

Create executable file and place the above lines as its content. Let's assume the file is called `script-indicator.py`. Depending on your needs and your script nature, you can use this *launcher* in one of the following ways:

```
./script-indicator.py /path/to/script.sh
./script-indicator.py /path/to/script.sh &
./script-indicator.py /path/to/script.sh > out.log &
./script-indicator.py /path/to/script.sh > /dev/null &
```

- Where `script.sh` is the one you want to indicate.

---

Screenshot made just when the `script.sh` is ended:

[image]

- Click on the image to see an animated demo.

---

Alternatively you can place the script in `/usr/local/bin` to be accessible as shell command system wide. You can download it from [this dedicate](https://github.com/metalevel-tech/powerNow) GitHub repository:

```bsh
sudo wget -qO /usr/local/bin/script-indicator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metalevel-tech/powerNow/master/powerNow.py
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/script-indicator
```

I've tested it with the following syntax:

```
script-indicator /path/to/script.sh
script-indicator /path/to/script.sh &
script-indicator /path/to/script.sh > output.log
script-indicator /path/to/script.sh > output.log &
script-indicator /path/to/script.sh > /dev/null
script-indicator /path/to/script.sh > /dev/null &
nohup script-indicator /path/to/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &
# etc...
```

Comment: Good job ! Already upvoted

Answer (score 6):

It's sufficient enough to have a script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true
do
    if pgrep -f gedit > /dev/null
    then

       printf "\r%b" "\033[2K"
       printf "Script is running"
    else
       printf "\r%b" "\033[2K" 
       printf "Script is not running."
    fi
    sleep 0.25
done
```

This is a very typical way and often used in shell scripts. What this does, is running continuously, and every quarter of a second it checks if your script is running via `pgrep -f`.  `if..fi` statements in shell scripts operate on exit status of commands, so `pgrep -f` returning successful exit status means it found your script's process and it's running. Otherwise, we go to else statement.

In both cases we print a line of text that tells the user if it's running or not. There's also added `printf "\r%b" "\033[2K"` for printing an escape sequence for clearing the line(just for cleaner output).

From there, the sky is the limit. You can pass that text to another process in terminal via pipe or you can pass the output from the monitoring script to [indicator-sysmonitor](https://askubuntu.com/a/512209/295286), which allows displaying custom information in the indicator. It can be installed via

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```

After that just configure the indicator to display a custom command which would be the monitoring script. Example of configuring a custom command can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/512209/295286).

Of course, one could write their own indicator in Python, but  this might be just an overkill when there's a tool for that already.

Comment: `indicator-sysmonitor` sounds useful, I should try it.

Answer (score 5):

#### With `osd_cat`

You can use `osd_cat` from the [`xosd-bin` [image: Install xosd-bin]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xosd-bin) package, e.g.:

```bsh
<<<"runs" osd_cat -d5 -i20 -o50 -f"-*-*-*-*-*-*-100-*-*-*-*-*-*-*" && firefox
```

This displays “runs” with font size `100` for `5` seconds at position `20,50` on the screen and starts `firefox` when it’s ready – you don’t need `sleep` with this approach. You can use `xfontsel` to get the X Logical Font Descriptor (this weird `-*-*-…` thingy) for the `-f` option, e.g. if you want to use a different font. Read `man osd_cat` for more options.

#### With `yad`

You could use [`yad` [image: Install yad]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/yad) as follows:

```bsh
yad --title=runs --text="it’s running!" --timeout=5 --button=Fire:1 --button=Abort:0 || firefox
```

This has the advantage that you can abort the command or execute it immediately, if you do nothing it will close after `5` seconds in this example.

Comment: Hi Dessert - thanks for your suggestion. What I'm looking for is something that remains on the screen for the entire 5 minutes.

Comment: @Sage. both do that, the `yad` window can be minimized, the osd text can not.

Comment: @Sage. I've tested the both proposed solutions and they work pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can take this [already working script `multi-timer`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837078/application-that-will-lock-screen-after-a-set-amount-of-time-for-ubuntu/837115#837115) and strip out the bulk of it for a generic count-down timer:

[image: spinning pizza.gif]

It uses the same `indicator-sysmonitor` described in Serge's answer.

The Systray part `Brightness: 2344` is also displayed by the same script.

If stripping out unneeded portions of the bash code is too difficult for new users I'd be happy to post a script here called `show-sleep` with the necessary limited functionality. Just post a comment below.