# How to update battery information in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, battery

I am trying to get information about my battery status using the following command from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/102863/742902).

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

But I am not getting any information about my battery. I get the following in my terminal

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Thursday 01 January 1970 05:30:00 AM IST (1531404045 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

How can I update my battery information, because it says

```
updated:              Thursday 01 January 1970 05:30:00 AM IST (1531404045 seconds ago)
```

Comment: Just to make sure you have the right battery use `ll freedesktop/UPower/devices` to see all available to pick.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I get `$ ll freedesktop/UPower/devices
ls: cannot access 'freedesktop/UPower/devices': No such file or directory
`. What should I do?

Comment: Darn phone put `/org/` in front like you did before.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1024771/566421